# PHP with MSSQL SQLSTATE 08001

Tags: php, sql-server, database-connection, php-7

I'm developing a project where I need to retrieve HUGE amounts of data from an MsSQL database and treat that data.

When I try to connect using the following code:

```
$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx\TMSSQL2008";

$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"BDxxxx", "UID"=>"SA", "PWD"=>"xxxxx");


$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);


if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

But the result is the following error:

> [SQLSTATE] => HYT00, 
>   [SQLSTATE] => 08001

I have configured the sql server to authenticate with credentials, name password and port 1433.

In fact, I was able to connect before using the driver and `mssql_connect` function, but since updating to PHP 7 this problem persists.

Comment: Potential duplicate of [How do I get mssql_connect to work using PHP7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768037/how-do-i-get-mssql-connect-to-work-using-php7)

Comment: this not the same

Comment: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585304/cant-cannect-to-sql-server-2008-express-database) suggests trying to connect to the default instance with only the server name and no instance may work `$serverName = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx";`  Are you able to ping the server ip?

Comment: Yes, ping and port 1433 open.

Comment: did you try the servername without the instance name?  have you created a second user and tried that user instead of the one you're trying now?  also, [check this Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405208/diagnosing-connection-to-sql-server)

Comment: Hi @SebastianSagardia, any solution found? I get the same error (also with `mssql-tools` cli). It seems, by sniffing, that in case of instance name no UDP communication with server's port 1434 (to get the instance port) is started as it should... While with the old extension it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Install sqsrv & sqlsrv_pdo extension then restart apache.

Installation Help:

1. download the ODBC drivers from this [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)
2. Copy the extensions php_pdo_sqlsrv & php_sqlsrv_80 in extension (ext) folder
3. Add the extensions in php.ini file & save.

Example For php 8 in windows

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_ts_x64.dll
```

Example for php 8 in linux

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64.dll
```

4. Restart the server/apache
5. Clear if any pre cache or session exist